# Groovy/Grails Float value and HTML5 number input

Tags: html, grails

In Groovy/Grails 2.0 I've got a domain with Float variable ( Float weight = 25.28 for example ). When Grails generates form with corresponding number input field, validation complains about the 25.28 value and will only accept an int value. Could someone illuminate what's going on with that? 
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
In Gails domain object(Double and BigDecimal for the sake of argument):

```
   Double weight = 350.26;
   BigDecimal width = 86.1;
```

Generated html:

```
<input id="weight" type="number" value="350.26" required="" name="weight">
<input id="width" type="number" value="86.1" required="" name="width">
```

... turns our FF 7 is fine with those numeric values and Chrome gives me "Invalid Value" and  only accepts integers. 
Any idea on what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you already try replacing the decimal separator with a comma in your HTML?

Comment: as @MarijnBouma suggested, certain locales use a comma for the decimal point instead of a dot when parsing (since the html input value gets submitted as a string), might want to double check that.

Comment: @vector: what did you end up doing here? How did you resolve the issue? I'm running into a similar issue using BigDecimal where I can't get the edit form to accept decimal values, even if I set an appropriate scale and min/max values in the constraints closure of the domain class and re-generate gsps.

Comment: jlpp... ended up setting the step value like step="0.001" or step="1", etc.

Comment: @vector: I'll put that into an answer for the next "me" that comes along?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using 'grails generate-all' _form.gsp files then update the generated _form.gsp input element to add step="0.001" or step="0.1" or step="any" or the like.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44116

One approach to get this update into all generated _form.gsp files is to run 'grails install-templates' then edit src/templates/scaffolding/renderEditor.template renderNumberEditor method and add step="any" to each

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. It was solved for me by editing the generated _form.gsp view, as jlpp said, but change the markup of the inputs to this:

```
<input id="weight" type="number decimal" value="350.26" required="" name="weight">
<input id="width" type="number decimal" value="86.1" required="" name="width">
```

Note the **type="number decimal"** to add decimal support on browser validation.
More a browser issue than a grails one.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You should set a Locale in your app. Probably the default locale of your server is different than on your client. However you are right, that grails should handle this.

Here is my workaround: Put this in your Bootstrap.groovy:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN);
```

Always use `formatNumber`, when printing to GUI:

```
${formatNumber(number:float, locale: Locale.GERMAN, format:'##0.00')}
```

It will do the appropriate decimal seperator. When you are in a controller and do not have a command-object, you will need to parse the value by yourself. Therefore:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = DecimalFormat.instance;
servicePrice.price = decimalFormat.parse(params.price);
```

You do not need to do this, when you use a command object instead.

Comment: ... that is a very good point. I'm just puzzled by the differences between Chrome and FF in terms of handling of the numeric input type.

Comment: according to this document, it make sense: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_input_types.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `step="any"` in your `input` tag.