# Which browsers are supported by HTML5-based dynamic scaffolding UI in Grails 2.x?

Tags: grails, cross-browser

Which browsers are supported by HTML5-based dynamic scaffolding UI in Grails 2.x?

By supported I mean: functional & looks good.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's as usable as the old scaffolding, if that is your concern. Well, there are just two issues, which ironically are present when using a HTML5-capable browser:

1. HTML5 overrides the messages.properties
   (as explained [here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8613))
2. Input of type="number"may lead to some problems
       (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052962/groovy-grails-float-value-and-html5-number-input))

Other than that is fine =)

Oh, and one last thing, it also includes CSS3 but that is just eye-candy like box-shadow and even when using a no-CSS3 browser scaffolding views look nice.